# Suppress ListView selection changed when clearing items from the observable collection

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

In my app I'm doing something like this in the view model for my listview:

```
public override void RefreshData() {
    base.RefreshData();

    ItemsSource.Clear();

    foreach (var item in ListViewData) {
        ItemsSource.Add(item);
    }

    RaisePropertyChanged("ItemsSource");
}
```

The call to .Clear() in the above causes the list's SelectionChanged event to be called. Considering not having access to the listview here, is there a good way to suppress or prevent that event from being called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think so. You may have to implement a property that you can set to tell the event handler to ignore the event for a while until everything is updated. I usually like to use something like "DeferSelectionChanged". Set it to true when starting the update and false when done.